# Как отобразить div по нажатию enter или по времени?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function searchDiv() {
  document.querySelector("input").oninput=function() {
    var elements=document.querySelectorAll("#sampleform  div.allDiv");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements,function(el,i) {
      el.style.display='none';
    });
    if(document.getElementById('textValue').value==1) {
      $(".div2").hide();
      $(".div1").show();
    }
    if(document.getElementById('textValue').value==2) {
      $(".div1").hide();   $(".div2").show();
    }
  }
}
```

Код HTML:

```
<input onlick="searchDiv()" class="inputTypeText" type="text" value="" size=57 name="textValue"  id="textValue" placeholder="Введите текстовое значение">
<div id="content">
 <div class="allDiv" id="div1">
  <div class="post inactive">
   <div class="title">
    <h3>Заголовок блока</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="entry" style="display:none;">
    <p><a href="#" title="">1</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" title="">2</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" title="">3</a></p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="allDiv" id="div2">
  <div class="post inactive">
   <div class="title">
    <h3>Заголовок блока</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="entry" style="display:none;">
    <p><a href="#" title="">1</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" title="">2</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" title="">3</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при вводе в текстовое поле блок div выдавался только в том случае, если:

1. При вводе в текстовое поле был нажат `enter`
2. Прошло более 1 секунды

Т.е при вводе в текстовое поле должна выполниться функция `searchDiv()`, но не сразу, а при выполнении п.1,2

Comment: Я бы повесил обработчик события keyPress на инпут и ждал бы нажатия enter, а понажатию запускал бы функцию с таймаутом

Comment: onkeyup. Получаете объект события, там вроде просто code называется. Проверяете код кнопки. Если код кнопки enter — выполнить условие. setTimeout записывайте в singleton-переменную. Каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку удаляйте таймаут, если не нажали — выполняется сам.